# Sort array by distance and have some indices relative to each other

Tags: javascript, sorting, ionic-framework

I have an array of objects:

- A: PICKUP A WITH DISTANCE 9.96
- B: DROPOFF A WITH DISTANCE 13.46
- C: PICKUP B WITH DISTANCE 4.46
- D: DROPOFF B WITH DISTANCE 1.06
- E: PICKUP C WITH DISTANCE 3.86
- F: DROPOFF C WITH DISTANCE 17.86

[]

```
0:{
   name: "A"
   distance: "9.96"
   key4: "zzz"
   log: "2"
   type: "Pickup"
}

1:{
   name: "B"
   distance: "13.46"
   key4: "zzz"
   key5: "true"
   log: "1"
   type: "Dropoff"
}

  2:{
   name: "C"
   distance: "1.06"
   key4: "ggg"
   log: "2"
   type: "Dropoff"
}

 3:{
       name: "D"
       distance: "4.46"
       key4: "ggg"
       key5: "true"
       log: "1"
       type: "Pickup"
    }

4:{
   name: "E"
   distance: "3.86"
   key4: "jjj"
   log: "2"
   type: "Pickup"
}

5:{
   name: "F"
   distance: "17.86"
   key4: "jjj"
   key5: "true"
   log: "1"
   type: "Dropoff"
}
```

ETA: 
My expected outcome:

- A: PICKUP C WITH DISTANCE 3.86
- B: PICKUP B WITH DISTANCE 4.46
- C: DROPOFF B WITH DISTANCE 1.06
- D: PICKUP A WITH DISTANCE 9.96
- E: DROPOFF A WITH DISTANCE 13.46
- F: DROPOFF C WITH DISTANCE 17.86

I've been trying in vain to first sort by distance but still have where "key4" of one object equals to "key4" of another object, and then if "log" of the first object is greater than the second "log" then the one with "log 2" is placed higher. It doesn't matter where the second object is placed as long as it is below the first object with all objects then respecting distance sorting. I'd like to end up with CEDABF. I would like for a matching pair of objects that Pickup is always before Dropoff no matter the distance difference but Pickup doesn't have to be directly before this Dropoff. The order could be Pickup1, Dropoff1, Pickup2, Pickup3, Dropoff3, Dropoff2, and this is based on distance. Here, Dropoff2 is after Pickup2 but not immediately after it.  I have so far been able to sort by ascending distance but then the criteria is ignored and likewise if if I sort by key4 and log then the distance is ignored. Any help would be appreciated.

This is what I've tried:

```
 let sortA = this.array.map((data, idx) => {
             return {idx: idx, data: data}
           })
            sortA.sort((a,b) => {
             if (a.data.key4 == b.data.key4) {
               if (a.idx > b.idx) 
               return -1; 
               if (a.idx < b.idx) 
               return 1; 
             } 
             return a.data.distance - b.data.distance
           })
this.newarray = sortA.map((val) => {
             return val.data
           })
```

And this gives:

- A: DROPOFF B WITH DISTANCE 1.06
- B: PICKUP C WITH DISTANCE 3.86
- C: PICKUP B WITH DISTANCE 4.46
- D: PICKUP A WITH DISTANCE 9.96
- E: DROPOFF A WITH DISTANCE 13.46
- F: DROPOFF C WITH DISTANCE 17.86

  0:{
      name: "C"
      distance: "1.06"
      key4: "ggg"
      log: "2"
      type: "Dropoff"
  }

  1:{
     name: "E"
     distance: "3.86"
     key4: "jjj"
     log: "2"
     type: "Pickup"
  }

  2:{
         name: "D"
         distance: "4.46"
         key4: "ggg"
         key5: "true"
         log: "1"
         type: "Pickup"
      }

  3:{
     name: "A"
     distance: "9.96"
     key4: "zzz"
     log: "2"
     type: "Pickup"
  }

  4:{
     name: "B"
     distance: "13.46"
     key4: "zzz"
     key5: "true"
     log: "1"
     type: "Dropoff"
  }

  5:{
     name: "F"
     distance: "17.86"
     key4: "jjj"
     key5: "true"
     log: "1"
     type: "Dropoff"
  }

This only sorts distances but ignores "key4" and "idx" such that Dropoff(DROPOFF B) with key4="ggg" is before it's corresponding Pickup.

I also tried:

```
this.array.sort(fieldSorter(['distance', '-key4']));
fieldSorter(fields) {
  return (a, b) => {
      return fields
          .map((o) => {
              let dir = 1;
              if (o[0] === '-') {
                 dir = -1;
                 o=o.substring(1);
                 console.log(o[0], 'ooo')
              }
              if (a[o] > b[o]) return dir;
              if (a[o] < b[o]) return -(dir);
              return 0;
          })
          .reduce((p,n) => {
              return p ? p : n;
          }, 0); 
  };
}
```

This gives me the same result as above:

- A: DROPOFF B WITH DISTANCE 1.06
- B: PICKUP C WITH DISTANCE 3.86
- C: PICKUP B WITH DISTANCE 4.46
- D: PICKUP A WITH DISTANCE 9.96
- E: DROPOFF A WITH DISTANCE 13.46
- F: DROPOFF C WITH DISTANCE 17.86

  0: {
      name: "C"
      distance: "1.06"
      key4: "ggg"
      log: "2"
      type: "Dropoff"
  }

  1:{
     name: "E"
     distance: "3.86"
     key4: "jjj"
     log: "2"
     type: "Pickup"
  }

  2:{
     name: "D"
     distance: "4.46"
     key4: "ggg"
     key5: "true"
     log: "1"
     type: "Pickup"
  }

  3:{
     name: "A"
     distance: "9.96"
     key4: "zzz"
     log: "2"
     type: "Pickup"
  }

  4:{
     name: "B"
     distance: "13.46"
     key4: "zzz"
     key5: "true"
     log: "1"
     type: "Dropoff"
  }

  5:{
     name: "F"
     distance: "17.86"
     key4: "jjj"
     key5: "true"
     log: "1"
     type: "Dropoff"
  }

This only sorts "key4" if two distances are equal.

Lastly, I tried if I added an attribute of "buyerId" on each Dropoff object. :

```
var stored = {}, newTab = [];
for(var i = 0, iLimit = array.length; i < iLimit; i++) {
    if(array[i].buyerId) {
        stored[i] = array[i];
    } else {
        newTab.push(array[i]);
    }
}

newTab.sort((a,b) => {
    var aVal = parseInt(a.distance);
    var bVal = parseInt(b.distance);
    if (aVal===bVal) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return aVal < bVal ? -1 : 1;
    }
});

for(var indice in stored) {
    newTab.splice(1, 0, stored[indice]);
}
```

The number after splice is just to show how Dropoffs would insert. Pickups are sorted by distance until the insert is made and then continued to be sorted afterwards.
This gives me:

- A: PICKUP C WITH DISTANCE 3.86
- B: PICKUP B WITH DISTANCE 4.46
- C: DROPOFF B WITH DISTANCE 1.06
- D: DROPOFF A WITH DISTANCE 13.46
- E: DROPOFF C WITH DISTANCE 17.86
- E: PICKUP A WITH DISTANCE 9.96

Comment: Your example is just sorted by distance. You say that you also mean to enforce this rule about key4 and log, but what's unclear - and not shown in your example - is what you would do if the record with log=2 also had a higher distance.  Once you clarify that, it *may* be possible to define a sorting order, but also it may not - because there are rules that a sorting order must follow in terms of consistency when comparing different elements, and these constraints may not work within those rules - in which case you'll have to do some custom re-ordering rather than fully rely on the sort method.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. If log=2 of a particular object has a higher distance than than its corresponding log=1 object (where key4 = key4) , then that log 2 object is still placed before its corresponding log 1 object.

Comment: As I said, that's somewhat unclear and I think the question needs an example that shows the expected result in this situation.

Comment: i want for each Pickup that comes first even if Dropoff is closer and if there is one Pickup1 (e.g distance=5) and another Pickup2 (e.g distance=7) while Dropoff1 (e.g distance=13)  and Dropoff2 (e.g distance=9), then the order would be Pickup1, Pickup2, Dropoff2, Dropoff1

Comment: I've edited my question to hopefully clarify more. Each type=Pickup object has a matching type=Dropoff. These are matched based on equal key4.

Comment: I'm trying to use a similar principle as DoorDash driver app. If Pickup1 (e.g distance=5) and another Pickup2 (e.g distance=13) while Dropoff1 (e.g distance=9) and Dropoff2 (e.g distance=2), then the order would be Pickup1, Pickup2, Dropoff2, Dropoff1. If Pickup1 (e.g distance=10) and another Pickup2 (e.g distance=13) while Dropoff1 (e.g distance=5) and Dropoff2 (e.g distance=2), then the order would be Pickup1, Dropoff1,Pickup2,  Dropoff2. Please let me know if you get my example and how to send others if needed. Thanks for your replies

Comment: If sorting is not doable, please advise how to refactor the code to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 0):

*UPDATE* - I've recognized a bit of a "grey area" around the limitations I cite of the `sort` method, which I am clarifying...

---

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Based on discussion in comments, I have some clearer idea of what you're attempting.  That said, a key element of a high-quality question is that it has an example that shows the expected behavior (*and* shows how that behavior differs from results from methods attempted).  Currently I see a single example which does not demonstrate any difference in results from "sort by distance".  While you separately describe why 'sort by distance' isn't what you want, an example should be present to demonstrate this difference.

Since there is not such an example (even after one was requested), I'll provide ad much of an answer as I can with the given information, but this comes with the reminder that on SO, the quality of answers will depend on the quality of the question.

---

So what I can definitely say is, you're running up against the bounds of what the stock `sort` method might be able to do.

When you provide an ordering function to `sort`, it has to be able to look at any two elements and say 'this one should go before that one', without needing context (such as whether a 3rd element meeting specific criteria might exist).  (There is a *small* amount of room to weasel around this limitation in some circumstances, which I'll talk about in a minute.)

So for example, if you had

- A: PICKUP A WITH DISTANCE 5
- B: DROPOFF A WITH DISTANCE 1
- C: PICKUP B WITH DISTANCE 3

the comparison function given to `sort` has to be able to look at `B` and `C` and, without any knowledge that `A` does or does not exist, decide whether `B` comes ahead of `C` in the list.  Likewise it has to be able to compare `A` and `C` without any knowledge about `B`.  And the results have to be consistent, such that if it says `x>y` and `y>z` then it must also say `x>z`.

Looking at `A` and `C` alone, it would seem `C` should come first.

Looking at `B` and `C` alone, it would seem `B` should come first.

Looking at `A` and `B`, we know that `A` must come first.

```
A > C > B > A
```

So there can be no consistent ordering rule to which the `sort` algorithm can apply.

But what about that room for weaseling?  Well, when you pass `A` and `C` to the sort function, you *could* encode the existence of `B` in the state of `A`

```
A = {
  "type": "PICKUP"
, "peer": B
, "distance": 5
}

B = {
  "type": "DROPOFF"
, "peer": "A"
, "distance": 1
}

// ...
```

Now you can write your comparison function to account for `B`'s distance value when comparing `A` with `C`.  But notice that the comparison *still* isn't operating on the context that '`B` is also in the list`- and in fact, this will behave the same *whether or not`B`is in the list*, because you have set`A`to a state which, according to your own rules, implies that`B` should be in the list.

But that brings us back to the same point...

The reason I keep harping on an example is, once it's time to resolve these discrepancies, there are multiple ways to do it, resulting in very different orderings of the nodes.  And you *need* to think about how you want those resolved in enough detail to provide the requested example,  And once you do, you may no longer need to provide the example because the solution will likely present itself.

What I *suspect* you'll need to do is, sort just the pickups, then walk the list, at each node determining whether it's best to proceed to the next pickup or complete one of the dropoffs for something you've already picked up.

Or maybe you have some consistent rule by which you can compare, for example, a given pickup (and its corresponding drop-off) against an unrelated drop-off (and its corresponding pickup), and produce stable/consistent ordering values from that.

But with the given information, these are only speculation.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback and for the welcome. Let me know if these are the examples that you required, which are the expected vs actual results when I use the functions above. Any thoughts on how to, as you say, sort the pickups and then determine at each node if to go to next pickup or dropoff?

Comment: Please also check my results for the last function I have in the original question. It can sort the Pickups but would still need some type of forEach method to compare each Dropoff.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've finally got it. I altered my last function, added splice and a type of bubble sort. This may help the next person.

```
var newTab = [], newTaby = [];
for(var i = 0, iLimit = array.length; i < iLimit; i++) {
    if(array[i].buyerId) {
        newTaby.push(array[i]);
    } else {
        newTab.push(array[i]);
    }
}

newTab.sort((a,b) => {
    var aVal = parseInt(a.distance);
    var bVal = parseInt(b.distance);
    if (aVal===bVal) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return aVal < bVal ? -1 : 1;
    }
});

for(let k = 0; k < newTaby.length; k++){
    for(let j = 0; j < newTab.length; j++) {
    if(newTaby[k].key5 == newTab[j].key5){
       newTab.splice(j+1, 0, newTaby[k])
     break;
     } 
  } 
}

for(let h=0; h < newTab.length - 1; h++) {
  for(let x=h+1; x < newTab.length; x++) {
    if (newTab[h].key4 != newTab[x].key4 && parseFloat(newTab[h].distance) > 
    parseFloat(newTab[x].distance) && newTab[h].log == '1'){
      let theGreater = newTab[h];
      newTab[h] = newTab[x]; 
      newTab[x] = theGreater;
     }
   }
}

console.log(newTab) //this will give the sorted array
```

Thanks for guiding me in the right direction! @Mark